# Unique numbers depending on date

Tags: excel, sum, unique, frequency, unique-values

I think I have been going at this a little bit to long and therefore maybe have become blindsided. I am looking for a way to identify the total number of orders given that the date is not the same. Each order can have several lines due to shipping on separate dates/months and I want these to become unique.

The data (saved as a table: tblorder) is much larger but here is an illustration for example:

```
Ordernr - date [YYYY-MM-DD]
200125 -    20150602
200222 -    20150604
200222 -    20150604
200237 -    20150604
200238 -    20150622
200230 -    20150625
200230 -    20150628
200125 -    20151202
200125 -    20151228
200125 -    20160202
200004 -    20160331
200125 -    20160401
```

To identify the unique number of orders regardless of date for

```
Start date=20150601
End date= 20161231
```

I use function:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(tblfaktura[date]<=<i>"start date";tblorder[Ordernr]);IF(tblfaktura[date]><i>"end date";tblorder[Ordernr]));1))
```

Using the above function I get a value of `6` unique orders. But I want to be able to count orders as unique when the date is not the same. So the result I want to achieve is `11`.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what your trying to do. Can you add a required output from the input you provided?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may achieve what you want by pivoting your data (in Tabular form with  Repeat item labels checked and no Subtotals) if ROW includes `date [YYYY-MM-DD]` above `Ordernr` and you [COUNT](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/count-sum-functions.html) the range displaying dates there.

Answer (score 0):

Entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(tblfaktura[[Ordernr ]]+tblfaktura[[ date]],tblfaktura[[Ordernr ]]+tblfaktura[[ date]])>0))
```

The above would be for all dates; but could be easily modified to include only a specified date range.

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY((tblfaktura[[Ordernr ]]+tblfaktura[[ date]])*(tblfaktura[[ date]]>=Start_Date)*(tblfaktura[[ date]]<=End_Date),(tblfaktura[[Ordernr ]]+tblfaktura[[ date]])*(tblfaktura[[ date]]>=Start_Date)*(tblfaktura[[ date]]<=End_Date))>0))
```

*The above formulas were tested with all of the dates being "real Excel dates", and not merely numeric representations as you show in your tables, although it should work with the numeric representations also.*